# How to pretty print xml and keep empty tag in Python?

Tags: python, xml

There are several things I want to achieve:

1. Pretty print with custom intend string
2. Keep empty tag `<tag></tag>` (because the files need to be edit later by human)
3. No xml header

`xml.dom.minidom` can do 1 and `xml.etree.ElementTree` can only do 2, 3. Is there any ways to achieve all of them?

Comment: If your xml is short, it is easy to do all you need manually with your favorite text editor. If it is long, people use xml editor to edit. We only require well-formed valid xml to work with.

Comment: @swatchai The purpose of writing this script is to generate the parts that can be automated. For example, a date field where each file is 5 days apart.

Comment: Beatiful Soup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/# could be useful.